# How to find the airline information based on the IATA code using Amadeus API

Tags: amadeus

I'm using the Amadeus [Flight Inspiration Search](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/flights/inspiration-search) sandbox API.

Here's an example of a JSON response:

```
{
      "destination": "WAS",
      "departure_date": "2017-04-01",
      "return_date": "2017-04-15",
      "price": "126.40",
      "airline": "DL"
    }
```

I looked through the other Amadeus APIs and could not find one that pulls the name of the airline based on the airline code (in the example above,  "airline": "DL"). How can we get the actual airline name?

Answer (score 3):

You can get this from [Open Travel Data](https://github.com/opentraveldata/opentraveldata), specifically the [Airlines](https://github.com/opentraveldata/opentraveldata/blob/master/opentraveldata/optd_airlines.csv) file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - we link to this at the bottom of the Getting Started page, but we'll find a way to make it more obvious. We also used to offer an API for this, but we removed it because it was used so infrequently!